# OpenMPI bind() failed on error Address already in use (48) Mac OS X

Tags: c, macos, sockets, mpi, bind

I have installed OpenMPI and tried to compile/execute one of the examples delivered with the newest version.
As I try to run with mpiexec it says that the address is already in use.

Someone got a hint why this is always happening?

```
Kristians-MacBook-Pro:examples kristian$ mpicc -o hello hello_c.c
Kristians-MacBook-Pro:examples kristian$ mpiexec -n 4 ./hello
[Kristians-MacBook-Pro.local:02747] [[56076,0],0] bind() failed on error Address already in use (48)
[Kristians-MacBook-Pro.local:02747] [[56076,0],0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Error in file oob_usock_component.c at line 228
[Kristians-MacBook-Pro.local:02748] [[56076,1],0] usock_peer_send_blocking: send() to socket 19 failed: Socket is not connected (57)
[Kristians-MacBook-Pro.local:02748] [[56076,1],0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Unreachable in file oob_usock_connection.c at line 315
[Kristians-MacBook-Pro.local:02748] [[56076,1],0] orte_usock_peer_try_connect: usock_peer_send_connect_ack to proc [[56076,0],0] failed: Unreachable (-12)
[Kristians-MacBook-Pro.local:02749] [[56076,1],1] usock_peer_send_blocking: send() to socket 20 failed: Socket is not connected (57)
[Kristians-MacBook-Pro.local:02749] [[56076,1],1] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Unreachable in file oob_usock_connection.c at line 315
[Kristians-MacBook-Pro.local:02749] [[56076,1],1] orte_usock_peer_try_connect: usock_peer_send_connect_ack to proc [[56076,0],0] failed: Unreachable (-12)
-------------------------------------------------------
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code.. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
-------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpiexec detected that one or more processes exited with non-zero status, thus causing
the job to be terminated. The first process to do so was:

  Process name: [[56076,1],0]
  Exit code:    1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. 
I have now changed the $TMPDIR environment variable with `export TMPDIR=/tmp` and it works.

Now it seems to me that the OpenMPI Session folder was blocking my communication. But why did it?
Am I missing something here?